# Tableau DATE AND TIME

Tags: excel, graph, tableau-api

I have a sample data , and need to create a graph like date and time based 
X-Axis date
Y-Axis time(hr)
TimeStamp

```
07/17/2018 17:27:31.106
07/17/2018 17:27:32.263
07/17/2018 17:27:33.388
07/17/2018 17:27:34.528
07/17/2018 17:27:35.622
07/17/2018 17:27:36.669
07/17/2018 17:27:37.716
07/17/2018 17:27:38.794
07/17/2018 17:27:39.841
07/17/2018 17:27:40.888
07/17/2018 17:27:42.997
07/17/2018 17:27:44.028
07/17/2018 17:27:45.103
```

Comment: please post if you have idea on how graph should look like?

Answer (score 0):

@Mr R Rao , you sample data only contains 1 date data (x) , and multiple hours data (y). if it was to be plotted, you'll need multiple dates + multiple hours data. With what you shared, we'll always end up drawing 1 straight line only. (:

Try this : put your data in 2 columns (include title will be better). 1 is the dates, 1 in the hours. then select both columns, then press F11. select the chart type. then edit as you need.